# "FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'typing._UnionGenericAlias'> is a valid pydantic field type"

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have the following Pydantic schema for a FastAPI app.

In the following schema, whenever I have `ParameterSchema` as the schema validator for `params`, it gives me the following error:

```
fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'typing._GenericAlias'> is a valid pydantic field type
```

I have no idea what's going on!

```
class ParameterSchema(BaseModel):
    expiryDate = Optional[datetime]

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True


class RequestProvisioningEventData(BaseModel):
    some_attribute: List[str]
    other_attribute: Optional[List[str]] = []
    bool_attribute: bool
    params: ParameterSchema

    class Config:
        use_enum_values = True
```

Comment: shouldn't that assignment in your ParameterSchema be a colon? `expiryDate: Optional[datetime]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `expiryDate` was *assigned* (`=`) a value

```
class ParameterSchema(BaseModel):
    expiryDate = Optional[datetime]
```

It should be using a [type hint](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/python-types/) (`:`):

```
class ParameterSchema(BaseModel):
    expiryDate: Optional[datetime]
```

Pay attention to use colons `:` for type hints, not equals `=`.